# Interpret range from dataframe column based on group ranges from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Recently I had help with a similar problem using R, now I am wanting to do this in python 2.7 using pandas. I have reviewed several similar issues on here but alas am still having issues.

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame([["1", "1", "2", "A"], ["2", "1", "2", "A"], ["3", "3", 
    "4", "B"], ["4", "3", "4", "B"], ["5", "5", "6", "C"], ["6", "5", "6", 
    "C"], ["7", "7", "8", "D"], ["8", "7", "8", "D"]], columns=['TimeStamp', 
    'Min', 'Max', 'Group'])
dfb = pd.DataFrame([['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8']], 
    columns = ['TimeStamp'])
```

[image]

I am looking for a way create a group id in dfb based on timestamps which fall within the min-max of each group in dfa. So, dfb_final:

[image]

This is for larger datasets and I have simplified the example. I just am not really sure what to do next. I got as far as getting the min max columns in dfa based on other answers. Very appreciative of learning from you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). The below solution assumes there are **no overlaps** in `Min` / `Max` values across groups. First convert some series to numeric so they are usable via NumPy:

```
dfa[dfa.columns[:-1]] = dfa[dfa.columns[:-1]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
dfb['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_numeric(dfb['TimeStamp'])
```

Note `datetime` / timestamp values *can* be converted to numeric equivalents if necessary.

Then extract unique groups and a flattened version of `Min` / `Max` values:

```
groups = dfa['Group'].unique()
vals = dfa.drop_duplicates('Group').loc[:, ['Min', 'Max']].values.ravel()
```

Finally, use `np.searchsorted` to position timestamps in `vals` and use the result to index `groups`:

```
dfb['Group'] = groups[np.searchsorted(dfb['TimeStamp'].values, vals) // 2]

print(dfb)

   TimeStamp Group
0          1     A
1          2     A
2          3     B
3          4     B
4          5     C
5          6     C
6          7     D
7          8     D
```

Comment: Hi jpp, thanks so much for helping me out. I am trying your code on my actual dataset and am getting "IndexError: index 573 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4". I am looking over the np.searchsorted documentation but there is not much. My dfb dataset's timestamp spans much longer than the timestamp in dfa, and I am not sure if that would be what is causing this error? I will keep tinkering but if you have any suggestions that would be great jpp- thanks for your help so far